# CODEPEN uploading audio

Tags: audio, codepen

I want to change the audio files played in this drum machine to my own audio files. I'm new to CODEPEN and don't understand how to upload my own audio files. The files here are amazon ones(?) but I just want to replace them with my own to create a different sounding drum machine.

https://codepen.io/mattgreenberg/pen/GRKxZLV

`audioLoader.load( "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/377560/AL_rhodes_chord_Bmin9.wav", buffer => { this.tonal3.setBuffer(buffer); this.tonal3.setVolume(0.5); this.tonal3.play(); this.tonal3.stop();`

This is one of the audio files that I want to swap out.